# How value comparison is done in HashSet, HashMap, etc

Tags: java, collections, hashcode, hashset

Below is the piece of code I tried; the output is also given.

My question is: I am setting the same String value in the setter of `HistoryTeardownDetails` for both objects `htd1` and `htd2`, so only one of the objects should have been allowed in the Hashset (as in the case of the String implementation).

Can anyone help me on how duplicates are eliminated in a Hashset or any collection using the concept of hashcodes?

```
public class HashSetTry {
public static void main(String[]args){
HistoryTeardownDetails htd1=new HistoryTeardownDetails();
htd1.setProcess("ashwin");
HistoryTeardownDetails htd2=new HistoryTeardownDetails();
htd2.setProcess("ashwin");

HashSet<HistoryTeardownDetails> hashSet1=new HashSet<HistoryTeardownDetails>();
System.out.println("First --> "+hashSet1);

hashSet1.add(htd1);


System.out.println("Second --> "+hashSet1);

hashSet1.add(htd2);

System.out.println("Third --> "+hashSet1);

HashSet<String> hashSet2=new HashSet<String>();

System.out.println("First --> "+hashSet2);

hashSet2.add("abc");


System.out.println("Second --> "+hashSet2);

hashSet2.add("abc");

System.out.println("Third --> "+hashSet2);

HashSet<String> hashSet3=new HashSet<String>();

String abc=new String("sakthi");

System.out.println("First --> "+hashSet3);

hashSet3.add(abc);

String abcd=new String("sakthi");

System.out.println("Second --> "+hashSet3);

hashSet3.add(abcd);

System.out.println("Third --> "+hashSet3);

}
}
```

Output:

```
First --> []
Second --> [com.ford.wqr.object.HistoryTeardownDetails@20662066]
Third --> [com.ford.wqr.object.HistoryTeardownDetails@20662066,    com.ford.wqr.object.HistoryTeardownDetails@20862086]

First --> []
Second --> [abc]
Third --> [abc]

First --> []
Second --> [sakthi]
Third --> [sakthi]
```

Answer (score 3):

- HashSets store unique elements. one simple rule

If you are adding an equal object to a hashset, then previous one will be replaced by the new one.

For the last two cases, you are using strings, for which the implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` method are already provided.

You need to provide `equals` and `hashcode` for your own class and then add into hashset.
Then only it will give desired output

- If the two objects are considered to be `equal`, then their hashcodes **MUST** be equal

I would recommend you use eclipse generated `equals` and `hashcode` methods for your own classes.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicates are determined by the `equals` method of the objects.

You need to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `HistoryTeardownDetails` class.

Answer (score 1):

HashSet.add actually uses a put method of internal HashMap. So lets see the source code of HashMap.put

```
386     public V put(K key, V value) {
387         if (key == null)
388             return putForNullKey(value);
389         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
390         int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
391         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
392             Object k;
393             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
394                 V oldValue = e.value;
395                 e.value = value;
396                 e.recordAccess(this);
397                 return oldValue;
398             }
399         }
400 
401         modCount++;
402         addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
403         return null;
404     }
```

Here at line 393 see that if the new key's hash is equal to any members hash then it checks if the key is same reference and check equality using equals method. If it exists then it returns without adding

Comment: -1 for going to the code instead of the documentation. The documentation is a guarantee and should be preferred over the code, which is merely one implementation.

Comment: @raptortech97... interesting downvote.. although I thought showing code will illustrate it more clearly

Answer (score 0):

I think in HashMaps equality is defined by having the same hash value of the hashCode() method in Object.

It is recommended if you provide an equals implementation, to always provide a hashCode implementation as well, to get a correct java.util.collection behaviour.